# MonoTouch.Dialog: How to make a RadioElement multiline?

Tags: xamarin.ios, multiline, monotouch.dialog

I am trying to develop an app with MonoTouch.  For some screens I create the UI in code.  I have a dynamically created `RadioGroup` with normally two to four `RadioElement`s (choices).  Sometimes the text (dynamic too) is too long for the `RadioElement` so that on an iPhone the text gets shorted by ... at the end.

I have googled and found no suggestion on how to create multiline `RadioElement`s.  I know you can create a `MultilineElement` if you want text over several lines, but how would I go about combining the two?  I assume I have to inherit from `RadioElement` and override some events, but which?  Is it the `MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableViewCell GetCell (MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView tv)` event?

Alternatively, how would you go about creating a `MultilineElement` that get a check mark on it when it got pressed/selected?

Or should I be thinking completely different?  Are there some other components that could solve this in a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

This is a sort-of solution (at least it solves my problem):

```cs
public class MultilineRadioElement : RadioElement
{
    public MultilineRadioElement (string caption, string group) 
      : base(caption, group) { }

    public override MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableViewCell GetCell 
      (MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCell (tv);
        cell.TextLabel.Lines = 2;
        return cell;
    }
}
```

When I now use a `MultilineRadioElement` instead of a `RadioElement` the text shows on two lines.  For me two lines are enough.  If the text is even longer and you still want to fit it inside the `RadioElement` at its current size you will probably have to calculate the size of the text and for example set the font in `cell.TextLabel.Font` to a more appropriate font.

I don't know how to make the `RadioElement` itself get bigger, so this is my best suggestion.

By the way, you should probably also add

```cs
protected override MonoTouch.Foundation.NSString CellKey 
{
    get { return base.CellKey; }
}
```

to the `MultilineRadioElement` as the intellisense in my Xamarin Studio suggests that this should be done when overriding `GetCell`, although it seems to work without it as well.

I am very happy if someone has an even better suggestion!!  (yes, two exclamation marks :) )